# How to simplify if statement?

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-logic

How can I simplify if statement like this

`!(!a || b)`?

And why it is actually possible?

UPD:

Sorry. Not optimize, but simplify :)

Comment: `"How can I optimize if statement like this"`: Optimize for what? By what criteria? Readability? Speed of operation? How is that line not optimized already?

Comment: You can rewrite it as `a && !b` (per [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)) - it won't be "more optimized" or "faster", but it might be more clear to read/understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on `De Morgan's Law` your condition `!(!a || b)` can be simplified like `(a && !b)`

cause `negataion` mark as `!`

`!(!a)` will become a

`!(||)` will become `&&`

`!(b)` will become `!b`

Answer (score 5):

You can *simplify* it a little more by applying [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
a && !b
```

… But I wouldn't call it "optimizing"! Really, it's such a tiny expression that you won't get any performance improvements by "optimizing" it (assuming that you're interested in *performance* improvements) - profile first and find the performance hotspots elsewhere. Or better yet, clarify what do you understand by "optimizing" , what's your definition for it.

**UPDATE**

OK, it was *simplifying* the expression what you intended all along. Then stick to the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: And the compiler would probably do that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [De Morgan theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)  it could be `(a && !b)`. Not sure if it makes any difference as you haven't specified what optimization you are looking for.